# Treatments of Lie theory and Noether theorems in tensor notation

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras, book-recommendation, tensors

I am looking for a conceptual treatment of Lie theory and Noether theorems that uses tensors calculus rather than exterior calculus.

I know that tensor calculus is not optimal for these subjects,
particularly since much of Lie theory does not assume a metric and covariant derivatives are secondary,
but I am not a professional mathematician and I find tensor notation much easier to read.
Whenever I read differential geometry using modern notation I seem to spend most of my energy just parsing formulas.

I would also prefer a more geometrical than algebraic treatment.

Comment: The combination of Lie Theory and [Noether's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether's_theorem) is a bit odd ? Or is there a Noether theory ? What about Helgason's book ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure it would match your expectations but have a look at Peter Olver's *Applications of Lie Groups to Differential Equations*.

Specifically for the mathematics surrounding the Noether theorem you also may wish to look at the book by Yvette Kosmann-Schwarzbach,  The Noether theorems. Invariance and conservation laws in the twentieth century, Springer, New York, 2011.

As for the Lie theory *per se*, *Naive Lie theory* by John Stillwell could be helpful.